# Change a td after cloning the element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the first TD in the `<tr>` element I am cloning.

Im cloning and inserting after the last `.deals_options` tr element

```
            var $orig = $('.deals_options:first');
            for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(amount - selectCount); i++) {
                $orig.clone().insertAfter('.deals_options:last');
            }
```

Works fine, but now inside this tr element `.deals_options`, I would like to add html inside the first `<td>`.

How can i insert text in the first td, in the cloned element i am inserting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. If you're really into one-liners (broken here onto multiple lines for clarity):

```
$orig.clone()
     .insertAfter('.deals_options:last')
     .find('td')
     .first()
     .html("new content");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/olohis/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/olohis/2/edit)

or if you really, really want to set the new content before it's added to the table:

```
$orig.clone()
     .find('td:first')
     .html("new content")
     .end()
     .insertAfter('.deals_options:last');
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/olohis/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/olohis/1/edit)

[`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) is one of the relatively obscure features of jQuery.

I'm not that into one-liners myself, so for me:

```
var clone;

// ...then in the loop...
clone = $orig.clone();
clone.find('td').first().html("new content");
clone.insertAfter('.deals_options:last');
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/olohis/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/olohis/3/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Find the first td in the cloned element and add some text to it:

```
var $orig = $('.deals_options:first');
for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(amount - selectCount); i++) {
     var clone = $orig.clone();
     clone.find('td:first').text("New Text");
     clone.insertAfter('.deals_options:last');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kgrhv/